# Convert Ubuntu 16.04 to PV domU on XenServer 6.5

Tags: 16.04, xen

Until recently, I've used templates from [stacklet.com](http://stacklet.com) to create my virtual machines on XenServer, but they haven't released one for Xenial yet, and now it looks like they may have ceased operations altogether.

So my question is: How can I create an Ubuntu 16.04 PV guest on XenServer 6.5?

I can install from an ISO image, and I've found [this link](https://www.cetic.be/Paravirtualize-an-Ubuntu-VM-using), which explains how to do it on older versions (at least until 12.10), but things appear to have changed enough with 16.04, that some of the steps in that process don't line up with the system.

Comment: It appears stacklet.com is back up, but they still don't have 16.04 templates yet, so I'm still interested in the answer to this question.